# Html form for wordpress questions

Tags: php, wordpress

i`m writing code in a custom template page from wordpress and i have the following form with the following php code right next to him. It aint worked and i have tried diferent options and still nothing.

```
<div class="su-tabs-pane su-clearfix">                  
            <form style="padding: 5px 25px; background:#00ABEC;" action="" method="GET">
                Nume:<input style="width:13.4%;" name="nume"  type="text" value="" />
                Specializare:<input style="width: 13.4%;" name="specializare" type="text" value="" />
                Spital:<input style="width: 13.4%;" name="spital"  type="text" value="" />
                <select name="filter">
                    <option value="ALL">Toate judetele</option>
                    <option value="AB">Alba</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Cauta" />
            </form> 

<?php
global $post;
if(isset($_GET["submit"])){

//variabile
$nume_searchq=$_GET["nume"];
$nume_searchq=strlower($nume_searchq);

$spec_searchq=$_GET["specializare"];
$spec_searchq=strlower($spec_search);

$instit_searchq=$_GET["spital"];
$instit_searchq=strlower($instit_searchq);





if($_GET['filter']=="ALL")  {
$results=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE LOWER(post_title) LIKE '%$nume_searchq%' OR LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%$spec_searchq%' OR LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%$instit_searchq%' ORDER by post_title");
}else if($_GET['filter']=="AB")  {
$results=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%Alba%' OR LOWER(post_title) LIKE '%$nume_searchq%' OR LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%$spec_searchq%' OR LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%$instit_searchq%'  ORDER by post_title");
}

$myposts = get_posts( $results);
foreach( $myposts as $post ){ 
     setup_postdata($post);
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '"> ' . get_the_title() . ' </a></li>';
}//end_foreach

 wp_reset_postdata();
 }//endIF_submit
 ?>
</div>
```

It actually dont display anyhing, i press submit and nothing happens. Tell me if i have some spelling problems or anything else...Thanks!

Comment: You could explain WHAT you want to do with this script and so on...

Comment: My wp_posts contains doctors. (post_title = their names, post_content= their specialization and zone where they work). I want to query wp_posts and retrieve the doctors with search options listed above by name, spec, hospital, and with the zone that he is working on by the dropdown list. Thats what i want to do

Answer (score 1):

You php code is wrapped in this conditional:

```
if(isset($_GET["submit"])){...}
```

However your form has no element with that name attribute ( `name="submit"` ), so that condition is always false.

change your submit button to:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Cauta" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. And another question is that the wp_posts retrieves me always the latest posts not the queried ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
<?php
```

global $post;
if (isset($_GET["filter"]) && !empty($_GET["filter"])) {

```
//variabile
$nume_searchq = $_GET["nume"];
$nume_searchq = strtolower($nume_searchq);

$spec_searchq = $_GET["specializare"];
$spec_searchq = strtolower($spec_search);

$instit_searchq = $_GET["spital"];
$instit_searchq = strtolower($instit_searchq);





if ($_GET['filter'] == "ALL") {
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE LOWER(post_title) LIKE '%$nume_searchq%' OR LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%$spec_searchq%' OR LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%$instit_searchq%' ORDER by post_title");
} else if ($_GET['filter'] == "AB") {
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%Alba%' OR LOWER(post_title) LIKE '%$nume_searchq%' OR LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%$spec_searchq%' OR LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%$instit_searchq%'  ORDER by post_title");
}

$myposts = get_posts($results);
foreach ($myposts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '"> ' . get_the_title() . ' </a></li>';
} //end_foreach

wp_reset_postdata();
```

} //endIF_submit
?>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).